# Avoid transformation text to link ie contentEditable mode

Tags: internet-explorer, hyperlink, contenteditable

In contenteditable div, in IE text like "http://blablabla", "www.blablabla", "bla@blabla" and so on automatically transforms into hyperlinks http://blablabla, [www.blablabla](http://www.blablabla), [bla@blabla](http://mailto:bla@blabla).
How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no cross-version solution.
In IE9 there is opportunity, allowing to disable automatic hyperlinking:

```
document.execCommand("AutoUrlDetect", false, false);
```

More information: [http://msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa769893%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),
[http://bytes.com](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/152771-disable-automatic-detection-hyperlinks-contenteditable-ie-5-5-a)