# Autolink URLs in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, ckeditor

In Internet Explorer, when you type a URL into a CKEditor `textarea`, it is automatically turned into a hyperlink. This does not work in Opera or Firefox. Is there a configuration setting in CKEditor to make this work across other browsers?

Comment: No, that's a feature specific to IE. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556007/avoid-transformation-text-to-link-ie-contenteditable-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a bit research and finded this:
http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/302

It says it's core feature of IE.

Answer (score 4):

There is a 3rd party plugin that does the requested feature: https://github.com/Gnodiah/ckeditor-autolink I did not test it though.

The feature request for CKEditor is reported in http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/7376