# Contenteditable bug when wrapping some text with link element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I am trying to figure out how twitter does the usergroup and hashtag implementation using a `contenteditable` element. When the user enters `@` or `#` the text with those special characters is wrapped with a link.

In my example, I can wrap the text with a link, but there is a bug that I have not yet resolved. When the text with `@` is wrapped with link, the cursor is moved to the start of the `<div>`.

I don't know what I am missing, so I need your help please! And if someone can explain me why this is happening, it will be welcomed.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/TheWebStudent/s0r82p52/2/)

Comment: Found that: http://jsfiddle.net/GEm75/ maybe it can help.

Comment: I replace `span` with `a` it doesn't work anymore

Comment: Check this question, may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249095/how-to-set-caretcursor-position-in-contenteditable-element-div/6249440#6249440

Comment: show what code you've got so far

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TheWebStudent/s0r82p52/2/: in this demo, it runs, but when the text is tranformed to link, the cursor move before the link

Comment: fix here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7556007/104380

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the painful world of `contenteditable`! I've discovered issues like this present themselves *constantly* as the solution becomes more complex- especially if you concern yourself with achieving consistent cross-browser behavior.

I see you query for the markup you wish to insert in your `<div>` with the value found on `valueOfQuery`. Since you are just calling `.html()` and injecting this over top your previous markup, your cursor has no idea where to place itself at this point.

You'll need to explore and become familiar with the [Range API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range), and in this example, we are saving our current selection before calling `.html()` then restoring it afterwards using these two functions - `saveSelection` and `restoreSelection`

```
var saveSelection, restoreSelection;

if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
    saveSelection = function(containerEl) {
        var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        var preSelectionRange = range.cloneRange();
        preSelectionRange.selectNodeContents(containerEl);
        preSelectionRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
        var start = preSelectionRange.toString().length;

        return {
            start: start,
            end: start + range.toString().length
        };
    };

    restoreSelection = function(containerEl, savedSel) {
        var charIndex = 0, range = document.createRange();
        range.setStart(containerEl, 0);
        range.collapse(true);
        var nodeStack = [containerEl], node, foundStart = false, stop = false;

        while (!stop && (node = nodeStack.pop())) {
            if (node.nodeType == 3) {
                var nextCharIndex = charIndex + node.length;
                if (!foundStart && savedSel.start >= charIndex && savedSel.start <= nextCharIndex) {
                    range.setStart(node, savedSel.start - charIndex);
                    foundStart = true;
                }
                if (foundStart && savedSel.end >= charIndex && savedSel.end <= nextCharIndex) {
                    range.setEnd(node, savedSel.end - charIndex);
                    stop = true;
                }
                charIndex = nextCharIndex;
            } else {
                var i = node.childNodes.length;
                while (i--) {
                    nodeStack.push(node.childNodes[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
} else if (document.selection) {
    saveSelection = function(containerEl) {
        var selectedTextRange = document.selection.createRange();
        var preSelectionTextRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        preSelectionTextRange.moveToElementText(containerEl);
        preSelectionTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", selectedTextRange);
        var start = preSelectionTextRange.text.length;

        return {
            start: start,
            end: start + selectedTextRange.text.length
        }
    };

    restoreSelection = function(containerEl, savedSel) {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(containerEl);
        textRange.collapse(true);
        textRange.moveEnd("character", savedSel.end);
        textRange.moveStart("character", savedSel.start);
        textRange.select();
    };
}
```

---

We then need to modify our current implementation within `keyup` as follows

```
var selection = saveSelection($('#result')[0]); // save cursor pos

$('#result').html(valueOfQuery);

restoreSelection($('#result')[0], selection); // restore cursor pos
```

---

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/eg18jr81/) - working example

Comment: You are a life saver!